# Import more than 25000 numbers (more than the limit of Google Contacts) in Android

Tags: contacts, import

I have generated a list of about 300000 numbers with regex to a text file. I know all of them are valid (pattern I mean) and most of them (like 80%) are real numbers (from somebody). Now I want to import them to phone contact in NOX (the Android emulator), but the problem is if I use Google Contacts, it has a limit of 25000 numbers.

If anyone has an idea, it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it myself:

1. I used MS Excel to change the format from TXT to CSV
2. And then I used Contacts from Windows to import the CSV
   and then exported them to a folder that contains 300000 contacts of VCARD or VCF files. You can find it on `C:\Users\USERNAME\Contacts`
3. And using CMD to export them all to ONE VCF

   ```
   copy *.vcf combined.vcf
   ```
4. And then used ADB to connect to NOX

   ```
   $ adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001 
   connected to 127.0.0.1:62001 

   $ adb devices
   List of devices attached
   127.0.0.1:62001 device
   ```
5. Copying the combined file into NOX SD card

   ```
   $ adb push contacts.vcf /sdcard/contacts.vcf
   $ adb sync
   ```
6. And then using the Contacts app from NOX to import the file from SD card.